# parse xml stdClass Object to json in php

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetDestinationsBasedOnSourceResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => 645Ahmednagar654Aurangabad663Bhusawal2530DeepNagar2868Dharangaon2309Erandol683Jalgaon2529Pahur735Varangaon3254Yawal
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any variable in PHP can be easily cast to json using the json_encode function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php